# How to post an current id

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am making a forum, and I can add a reaction to save in the database, the only problem now is that it will leave empty id in the database.

**The database**:
[image]

**How it will post it now**:
[image]

Now I need to find a way to add the `ledenpagina_id`, `topic_id` and `klant_id` automatic. The `klant_id` needs to be set based on the klant session, but I am not sure how to get that.

The `topic_id` is set as `active_id` like this:
    $actieftopicid = $topic['id'];`

But I don't know how to add that in the post so it will save it the correct way in the database.

I have tried doing this:

```
$q1['topic_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST[$topic['id']]);
```

But that isn't working.

The code to post it in the database:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['react_btn'])){
     unset($q1);
     $q1['reactie'] = $app->check_string($_POST['reactie']);
     $q1['topic_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST[$topic['id']]);

      $app->insert_query('reacties', $q1, 'id');
      }  

      ?>
     <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="comment">Reactie:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="reactie" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="react_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Plaats reactie</button>
            </div>              
      </form>
```

Comment: What is the question? Please be explicit.

Comment: Have u made ur table id as `primary` & `auto increment` & `not null`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `id` of the topic into the `form` like this:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="comment">Reactie:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="reactie" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="<?php echo $topic['id']; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="react_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Plaats reactie</button>
        </div>              
  </form>
```

and then you can use it like `$_POST['topicid']`, since that is the `name` of the `hidden` `input`. Also, instead of

```
unset($q1);
```

you need to initialize `$q1` properly:

```
$q1 = array();
```